# Plotting metabolic networks?

Tags: visualization, bioinformatics, graph-visualization, sbml

I need to draw a map of the core metabolism of E.coli. Associated with each reaction in the map I have a number that indicates the flux through this reaction. I want the map to reflect these fluxes through the color of each reaction in the map.

I have tried using tools like Mathematica and Cytoscape, but it is very hard to get a nice layout of the metabolic network. I have seen maps of E.coli metabolism which look very nice on paper. What I need is a map like these, but where I can define the colors of the reactions.

There are some tools available, for example, metdraw.com. But when I upload my E.coli SBML model, the plot layout is a disaster. There used to be a web IPython notebook that one could use for some prebuilt models, where you just had to input the reaction fluxes. But now it's gone: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/opencobra/cobrapy/blob/master/documentation_builder/visbio.ipynb

See the image below for an example. Forget about the yellow bounding boxes delimiting compartments. I can spare those.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some tracking of the broken link you posted brings me to Escher, which appears to be what visbio is now called:

https://github.com/zakandrewking/escher

For example see:

https://cobrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/escher.html

Escher is part of Cobrapy:

http://opencobra.github.io/cobrapy/

A software suite to model biological networks.